# Redis Multi-AZ feature in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation

I'm designing a template which includes a Redis service and I would like to enable Multi-AZ feature in Redis such that upon the primary cluster failure, read replica can be promoted to primary. I looked in the CloudFormation documentation but I couldn't find this feature i.e. Multi-AZ. It is available for RDS service but not for Redis. Can I know how I can include the feature for redis such AWS take cares of the automatic failover ?

Source:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html

The list of properties that are available for the elastic cache are listed below.

```
"AutoMinorVersionUpgrade"    : Boolean,
"AZMode"                     : String,
"CacheNodeType"              : String,
"CacheParameterGroupName"    : String,
"CacheSecurityGroupNames"    : [ String, ... ],
"CacheSubnetGroupName"       : String,
"ClusterName"                : String,
"Engine"                     : String,
"EngineVersion"              : String,
"NotificationTopicArn"       : String,
"Port"                       : Integer,
"PreferredAvailabilityZone"  : String,
"PreferredAvailabilityZones" : [String, ... ],
"PreferredMaintenanceWindow" : String,
"SnapshotArns"               : [String, ... ],
"SnapshotName"               : String,
"SnapshotRetentionLimit"     : Integer,
"SnapshotWindow"             : String,
"Tags"                       : [Resource Tag, ...],
"VpcSecurityGroupIds"        : [String, ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This are the two ways you can set Redis to use Multi Az programatically.

Using CLI

```
aws elasticache modify-replication-group \
    --replication-group-id myReplGroup \
    --automatic-failover-enabled
```

Using Elasticache API

```
https://elasticache.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
    ?Action=ModifyReplicationGroup
    &AutoFailover=true
    &ReplicationGroupId=myReplGroup
    &Version=2015-02-02
    &SignatureVersion=4
    &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
    &Timestamp=20140401T192317Z
    &X-Amz-Credential=<credential>
```

This are some of the notes that you should read while selecting Multi Az for redis.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoFailover.html#AutoFailover.Notes

For Cloud Formation below are the Properties:

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "AutomaticFailoverEnabled" : Boolean,
    "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade" : Boolean,
    "CacheNodeType" : String,
    "CacheParameterGroupName" : String,
    "CacheSecurityGroupNames" : [ String, ... ],
    "CacheSubnetGroupName" : String,
    "Engine" : String,
    "EngineVersion" : String,
    "NotificationTopicArn" : String,
    "NumCacheClusters" : Integer,
    "Port" : Integer,
    "PreferredCacheClusterAZs" : [ String, ... ],
    "PreferredMaintenanceWindow" : String,
    "ReplicationGroupDescription" : String,
    "SecurityGroupIds" : [ String, ... ],
    "SnapshotArns" : [ String, ... ],
    "SnapshotRetentionLimit" : Integer,
    "SnapshotWindow" : String
  }
}
```

You have to tweak this property for Multi Az

AutomaticFailoverEnabled

Indicates whether Multi-AZ is enabled. When Multi-AZ is enabled, a read-only replica is automatically promoted to a read-write primary cluster if the existing primary cluster fails. If you specify true, you must specify a value greater than 1 for the NumCacheNodes property. By default, AWS CloudFormation sets the value to true.

For more information about Multi-AZ, see [Multi-AZ with Redis Replication Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoFailover.html) in the Amazon ElastiCache User Guide.

Note
You cannot enable automatic failover for Redis versions earlier than 2.8.6 or for T1 and T2 cache node types.
Required: No

Type: Boolean

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html

Comment: Thanks error2007s but I want this feature to be part of the CloudFormation template for the redis cluster. Is there any way I can configure ?

Comment: Check My Edited Answer

Comment: Thanks Error. This is only supported for memcached but what about redis engine ?

Comment: So I would use Replication groups for redis when designing the template in the CloudFormation. I presume that there is no need of the cachecluster service.